# Handlebars is undefined in IE8 with requireJS

Tags: internet-explorer-8, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars v3.0.0 (non-AMD) and requireJS with the following configuration:

```
require.config({
  deps: [ 'main' ],
  paths: {
    'handlebars' : 'lib/handlebars'
  },
  shim: {
    handlebars: {
      exports: 'Handlebars'
    }
  }
});
```

And calling for it like this:

```
define( [
  'handlebars'
],
function( Handlebars ){
  'use strict';

  var HBS = Handlebars.default;
...
```

This works on all modern browsers, IE9, IE10 & IE11 but not in IE8. 
Handlebars is undefined in IE8 as shown below:

[image: Handlebars IE8 bug]

I'm using the non AMD version (hence I'm shim in it), actually I copied and pasted the code this CDN link throws:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
```

NOTE-A: Handlebars works if I include the above script tag in my index page instead of using it with requireJS.

NOTE-B: Already tried using the AMD version, same thing.

NOTE-C: I'm using a virtual machine for IE8 testing.

NOTE-D: IE8 Document Mode is IE8 Standards

Any help with this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: Nope. However, because of the close deadline of the project I had to look for another alternative and underscore´s micro templating fitted pretty well and worked on IE8 without trouble.